# Lost connection when scp into a linux machine

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I tried to scp a file from my local directory into my school linux machine, but it lost connection after I entered my password.

The command I used was similar to

```
scp <filename> <linuxRemoteAddress>:311/.
```

After I typed this command, the machine told me to enter my password. And then I entered my password, and after a while the terminal shows "lost connection"

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **rsync** with `--progress` and `-v` flag to see the copy progress bar. Your command should look like this:

```
rsync --progress -v <src file> <destination>
```

Comment: Please avoid answering [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) fodder. Instead, close it and move on. It is sometimes helpful to suggest a site where the question may be on-topic.